# Parsing a string using regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

```
my_string = "Value1=Product Registered;Value2=Linux;Value3=C:5;C++:5;Value4=43;"
```

I was using the following regex:

```
tokens = re.findall(r'([^;]+)=([^;]+)', line, re.I)
```

I need to parse value1, value2, etc and put their values into the database. For example, I need to store `"C:5;C++:5"` for `value3` -- but by using the above regex I can only store `C:5`, because I parse based on `";"`. What would be a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do the fields always start with the string "Value"?

Comment: This looks like a weird language. If one of the RHSs is e.g. `;Value=foo` it's undecidable. Or is there some constraint on the LHS and RHS?

Comment: Do you want "value3" = "C:5;C++:5;Value4:43" or "C:5;C++:5"?  Do you have a specification for this language?  Where does the value part stop?

Comment: Is it supposed to be `Value4:43` or should it be `Value4=43`?

Comment: No the fields don't always start with value. it could be any word. I created a dummy example to describe this problem. I am trying to parse a file line by line and each line contains a set of fields. my regex works fine until it comes to Value3 which contains semi colon separated values. that causes the inconsistency. Let me know of additional questions. Thanks.

Comment: my bad it is Value4=43. The real problem is value3. How do i parse that?

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use a regex for this? If the keys and values can't contain semicolons, you can just do my_string.split(';') (or [kv.split('=') for kv in my_string.split(';')] if you want pairs). If they _can_ contain semicolons, then regexes won't work either.

Comment: How is any parser supposed to know whether this is "Value3" = "C:5;C++:5" or "Value3" = "C:5" and "C++:5;Value4" = "43"? If you can quantify the answer to that, someone can tell you how to turn that answer into code. If not, the language is ambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems reasonable to assume that the key names don't contain semicolons. If this isn't true, then as Philipp pointed out the language is ambiguous. But if not, you can use a lookahead to tell which `;` is the separator: it has to be followed by a sequence of things that aren't either `;` or `=`, and then either an `=` or end-of-string:

```
>>> my_string = "Value1=Product Registered;Value2=Linux;Value3=C:5;C++:5;Value4=43;"
>>> r = re.compile(r'([^;]+)=([^=]+);(?=[^;=]*(?:=|$))')
>>> r.findall(my_string)
[('Value1', 'Product Registered'),
 ('Value2', 'Linux'),
 ('Value3', 'C:5;C++:5'),
 ('Value4', '43')]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as the OP made clear in one of his edits, the values _can_ contain semicolons, which means the language can't be parsed by regex (or, in fact, anything—unless there's some extra rule here, it's ambiguous).

Comment: @abarnert By "values" I meant the things like "value1". I'll rephrase, but the code shows that it clearly does work for his example.

Comment: OK, right, if the values can contain semicolons but the keys can't, then it's not ambiguous, and it's parseable by your regex. And I think your answer now makes it clear what exactly the assumptions are. So, +1.

Comment: @JBernardo Sure; switched it.